# How to display Buddypress profile field content within the post loop

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a Buddypress profile field called “Bio”, and I’d like to display it’s content in the post footer, to show the author’s bio.

I’ve tried

```
<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=Bio');?>
```

and

```
<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'Bio' );?>,
```

but I’m still pretty lost.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Well of course you would first want to get the current user ID:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

Then, as confirmed through Buddypress 1.5:

```
<?php bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>$current_user_id,'field'=>'bio' )); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this worked in author boxes:

```
<?php bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'field'=>'NAME_OF_THE_FIELD' )); ?>
```